# Prove by induction that $(1 + x)^n \ge 1 + nx$ for all $n \in\Bbb N$

Tags: inequality, induction

Let $x \gt -1$. Prove by induction that $(1 + x)^n \ge 1 + nx$ for all $n \in\Bbb N$.

Can anyone show me how to prove by induction? I'm having problem on solving this question. Please prove with details and the three steps.

Comment: Yea but it needs to be proved by induction

Answer (score 2):

For $n=1$ it's obvious.

Let $(1+x)^k\geq1+kx$.

Hence, $$(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)(1+x)^k\geq(1+x)(1+kx)=1+(k+1)x+kx^2\geq1+(k+1)x$$
and we are done!

Comment: Should that be $(k+1)x$ after you expanded the two brackets, instead of $(k+1)$?

Comment: @Dave I fixed my post. Thank you!